# In Eclipse, hide files ending in tilde `~`

Tags: eclipse, emacs, hidden-files

Eclipse, by default, hides files that begin with `.` in the Package Explorer, Navigator, and other file views (e.g. `.classpath`, `.settings`, etc). Is it possible to hide files which end in `~` (e.g. `somefile.txt~`).

Yes, these are Emacs backup files, created while using both Eclipse and Emacs on the same project.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the package explorer toolbar, there should be an icon that makes a dropdown menu appear; in that menu, select "Filters…".

Edit: see [this link](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/tasks/tasks-48b.htm) for an example of the icon, denoted the 'Menu button'

Comment: Things have changed, apparently in the Mars release.  The dropdown menu has a customize view option, and a filters tab in there.  However, the filters list doesn't seem to include a 'emacs backup files' option, nor do I know how to add such a filter.

Answer (score 5):

use `backup-directory-alist` in your emacs config to stash away the emacs backups in a different directory

Comment: In the end I went with the Eclipse setting, but I find this a useful suggestion - I just happen to like where the backups are, but don't want to see them.

Answer (score 1):

In the Mars release, for the project you want to filter files on:

- Project > properties > Resource/Resource Filters, Add Filter...
- In the Add Resource Filter dialog:

  - Select "Exclude all"
  - Select "Files"
  - Set "All Children" to true
  - Filter values: "Name" "matches" "*~"

Reference: http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-97.htm